# Facet_Wrap is congested for More levels of factor in my dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset `df` where I need to find the correlation between the `X` and `Y` variables. I also need to see the correlation with different locations. My issue is that I have many locations (say 95) and when I plot the code with `ggplot()`, the output is congested and not very clear. Is it possible to increase the layout of `ggplot()` so that I can scroll down to see the plots. I cannot share the sample here since it is huge. This is how I tried:

```
        dput(df)
structure(list(X = c(60, 72, 86, 82, 20, 43, 5, 9, 54, 53, 65, 
73, 56, 80, 38, 14, 83, 85, 6, 61, 93, 39, 31, 86, 28, 26, 45, 
17, 34, 95, 59, 81, 73, 20, 75, 77, 75, 32, 20, 67, 44, 56, 76, 
76, 15, 93, 55, 77, 93, 90, 22, 53, 23, 78, 96, 76, 20, 49, 7, 
32, 96, 20, 29, 25, 9, 59, 57, 15, 31, 27, 12, 14, 35, 71, 40, 
68, 37, 54, 25, 70, 59, 58, 5, 49, 82, 14, 16, 9, 98, 86, 30, 
38, 16, 64, 77, 27, 16, 41, 32, 57, 40, 15, 63, 36, 95, 85, 62, 
54, 67, 32, 7, 98, 15, 29, 66, 36, 26, 41, 100, 5, 18, 63, 100, 
51, 28, 6, 12, 98, 13, 67, 91, 55, 10, 30, 32, 23, 28, 41, 79, 
80, 22, 63, 23, 96, 21, 35, 38, 73, 84, 72, 17, 49, 40, 100, 
18, 9, 79, 65, 35, 80, 8, 71, 85, 60, 56, 66, 99, 73, 74, 100, 
22, 39, 78, 7, 97, 69, 68, 88, 11, 69, 43, 95, 65, 68, 78, 44, 
74, 73), Y = c(78, 61, 66, 70, 53, 28, 76, 86, 82, 19, 98, 12, 
31, 86, 59, 91, 93, 64, 78, 12, 41, 99, 66, 64, 11, 57, 13, 35, 
43, 67, 6, 72, 97, 31, 61, 48, 79, 69, 40, 44, 65, 46, 39, 75, 
27, 6, 74, 46, 71, 42, 28, 30, 83, 82, 16, 34, 49, 15, 67, 66, 
30, 26, 55, 12, 19, 47, 90, 50, 27, 56, 40, 92, 39, 63, 15, 95, 
72, 58, 12, 15, 27, 44, 16, 9, 25, 19, 21, 43, 59, 48, 7, 12, 
60, 65, 86, 53, 48, 73, 53, 70, 38, 43, 35, 18, 30, 62, 94, 61, 
49, 5, 79, 33, 73, 91, 19, 81, 24, 93, 95, 73, 70, 92, 45, 33, 
24, 20, 96, 11, 72, 51, 87, 19, 68, 47, 7, 98, 73, 27, 51, 10, 
46, 27, 95, 38, 97, 27, 13, 28, 56, 61, 58, 26, 11, 69, 5, 84, 
7, 11, 19, 55, 94, 25, 29, 32, 83, 78, 45, 29, 80, 30, 68, 91, 
63, 16, 14, 75, 63, 17, 83, 7, 47, 71, 78, 92, 87, 14, 7, 21), 
    Location = c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8", 
    "L9", "L10", "L11", "L12", "L13", "L14", "L15", "L16", "L17", 
    "L18", "L19", "L20", "L21", "L22", "L23", "L24", "L25", "L26", 
    "L27", "L28", "L29", "L30", "L31", "L32", "L33", "L34", "L35", 
    "L36", "L37", "L38", "L39", "L40", "L41", "L42", "L43", "L44", 
    "L45", "L46", "L47", "L48", "L49", "L50", "L51", "L52", "L53", 
    "L54", "L55", "L56", "L57", "L58", "L59", "L60", "L61", "L62", 
    "L63", "L64", "L65", "L66", "L67", "L68", "L69", "L70", "L71", 
    "L72", "L73", "L74", "L75", "L76", "L77", "L78", "L79", "L80", 
    "L81", "L82", "L83", "L84", "L85", "L86", "L87", "L88", "L89", 
    "L90", "L91", "L92", "L93", "L94", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", 
    "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8", "L9", "L10", "L11", "L12", "L13", 
    "L14", "L15", "L16", "L17", "L18", "L19", "L20", "L21", "L22", 
    "L23", "L24", "L25", "L26", "L27", "L28", "L29", "L30", "L31", 
    "L32", "L33", "L34", "L35", "L36", "L37", "L38", "L39", "L40", 
    "L41", "L42", "L43", "L44", "L45", "L46", "L47", "L48", "L49", 
    "L50", "L51", "L52", "L53", "L54", "L55", "L56", "L57", "L58", 
    "L59", "L60", "L61", "L62", "L63", "L64", "L65", "L66", "L67", 
    "L68", "L69", "L70", "L71", "L72", "L73", "L74", "L75", "L76", 
    "L77", "L78", "L79", "L80", "L81", "L82", "L83", "L84", "L85", 
    "L86", "L87", "L88", "L89", "L90", "L91", "L92", "L93", "L94"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -188L), class = "data.frame")



ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=Location)) +
    geom_point() + 
    facet_wrap("Location",scales = "free_y") + 
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

The result is very congested and it is fitting all 95 locations one screen only.

Comment: DevP, this is a little under-informed: we don't have sufficient data, nor do we see what you mean by "congested", so anything is speculation. Please provide sufficiently-large sample data, perhaps literally just `data.frame(...)` with as many groups/facets as you really have, with a single point in each facet.

Comment: Having said that, "too congested" is dependent on the canvas size (PDF letter/legal/a4/..., web-page dimensions/dpi), so that part of it is very contextual. Additionally, it might be useful to split your image into multiple different images with a smaller group in each image.

Comment: @r2evans Please review my edited question

Comment: "Scrolling" is not a thing in normal R graphics, including base, `ggplot2`, and other `lattice`-based methods, primarily because they all are relatively "static". `plotly` can provide such interactive use, allowing zooming and filtering and such. The use of `scales="free_y"` is definitely taking up a lot of room, as the y-axis is added to each facet.

Comment: Is this going into a static report (word, r-markdown, powerpoint), as a shiny app, or in what form?

Comment: Power Point. But the point is I am not able to make any conclusions since the plots are small.

Comment: (BTW: how were you going to "scroll" in powerpoint?)

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a visualization of the correlation between x and y for each location, I would suggest making one plot that shows all of this information.  Using a great function found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/r-compute-correlation-by-group), you can calculate the correlation between x and y for each group and store the results in a simple data frame.  Then, you can plot the correlations by location.  This plot generated here orders the correlations by smallest to largest.

```
#Makes a dummy data set with 95 locations, 30 repeated observations/location
df <- data.frame(location = rep(1:95, 30), x = rnorm(2850) , y = rnorm(2850))

require(plyr)

#Function that calculates correlation and returns value in data frame
func <- function(df)
{
return(data.frame(COR = cor(df$x, df$y)))
}

#Run function on your dataset
df_cor <- ddply(df, .(location), func)

require(ggplot2)
require(tidyverse)

#Plot results
df_cor %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = reorder(location, COR), y = COR)) + 
 geom_point() +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
 xlab("Location")
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not completely clear what you want based on your question, but if I understand correctly you have a dpi problem. If you export your plot and make it larger, you'll get more of what you want.

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_x <- rnorm(130)
my_y <- (my_x * 2) + 5
my_locations <- rep(letters, 5)
my_data <- tibble(my_x, my_y, my_locations)

ggplot(my_data, aes(x=my_x, y=my_y, fill=my_locations)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(facets="my_locations",scales = "free_y") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

The output looks very congested in the plot window:
[image]

But if you save it as a larger image it looks great:
[image]

Comment: Yes you are right. I will try to save and see once. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `facet_wrap`, I assume that you aren't necessarily needing perfect side-by-side(-by-above/below) comparison of each facet. It would be *nice*, of course, but with 94 such facets (and limited screen real-estate), I suggest you can break it down into multiple plots.

```r
subgroups <- split(unique(df$Location), (seq_along(unique(df$Location))-1) %/% 16)
str(subgroups)
# List of 6
#  $ 0: chr [1:16] "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" ...
#  $ 1: chr [1:16] "L17" "L18" "L19" "L20" ...
#  $ 2: chr [1:16] "L33" "L34" "L35" "L36" ...
#  $ 3: chr [1:16] "L49" "L50" "L51" "L52" ...
#  $ 4: chr [1:16] "L65" "L66" "L67" "L68" ...
#  $ 5: chr [1:14] "L81" "L82" "L83" "L84" ...

for (subgrp in subgroups) {
  gg <- ggplot(df[ df$Location %in% subgrp, ], aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=Location)) +
      geom_point() + 
      facet_wrap("Location",scales = "free_y") + 
      theme(legend.position = "none") 
  ggsave(sprintf("subplot_%s-%s.png", subgrp[1], tail(subgrp, 1)), gg)
}
```

Which goes from the left (all) to the right (16 `Location`s at a time):

[image: side-by-side ggplots]

(and you'll have six such plots). The number of groups to include in each plot is completely up to you ... 16 was a simple number that gave a mostly-balanced set of sub-groups.

---

Or ... you can just increase the size of the PNG with `width=` and `height=`:

```r
gg <- ggplot(df, ...) + ... # full image, no grouping
ggsave(sprintf("subplot_%s-%s.png", subgrp[1], tail(subgrp,1)), gg,
  width=16, height=16)
```

[image: full-size image]